# I have a issue int spritekit game I am making

Tags: arrays, nsmutablearray, sprite-kit

Hi guys I am not getting the physics applied to my images inside my array.
all I am trying to do is to randomly pick a bunch of images to pop up on the scene at random locations and what I did was declare them first as SKSpriteNode, gave them their sprites and then used their physics and then their identifier "iamge1...6" in the array. the only reason I am doing this is because I need to have several different sprites or enemies I should say to pop up in the scene but I need to be able to shoot them right and I would need physics applied for that. so am I following a right approach here?

My Code:

```
- (void) itemsONScene {
image1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b1"];
image2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b2"];
image3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b3"];
image4 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b4"];
image5 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b5"];
image6 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b6"];
image7 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"b7"];

image1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:image1.frame.size.width/2];
image1.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
image1.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
image1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsimage1Category;
image1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsbulletCategory;
[image1 attachDebugRectWithSize:image1.size];
//////
image2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:image2.frame.size.width/2];
image2.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
image2.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
image2.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsimage2Category;
image2.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsbulletCategory;
[image2 attachDebugRectWithSize:image2.size];
//////
image3.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:image3.frame.size.width/2];
image3.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
image3.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
image3.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsimage3Category;
image3.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsbulletCategory;
[image3 attachDebugRectWithSize:image3.size];
//////
image4.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:image4.frame.size.width/2];
image4.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
image4.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
image4.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsimage4Category;
image4.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsbulletCategory;
[image4 attachDebugRectWithSize:image4.size];
//////
image5.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:image5.frame.size.width/2];
image5.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
image5.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
image5.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsimage5Category;
image5.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsbulletCategory;
[image5 attachDebugRectWithSize:image5.size];
/////
image6.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:image6.frame.size.width/2];
image6.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
image6.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
image6.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsimage6Category;
image6.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsbulletCategory;
[image6 attachDebugRectWithSize:image6.size];
/////
image7.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:image7.frame.size.width/2];
image7.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
image7.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
image7.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsimage7Category;
image7.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsbulletCategory;
[image7 attachDebugRectWithSize:image7.size];
/////
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"b1", @"b2", @"b3", @"b4", @"b5", 
@"b6", @"b7", nil];
NSUInteger arraypicker = arc4random() % [myArray count];
NSUInteger i = arraypicker;
ds = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
sprites = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:ds];
sprites.name = @"items";
sprites.position = CGPointMake(ScalarRandomRange(325, 525),   
ScalarRandomRange(self.size.height/1.20, self.size.height/12));
sprites.xScale = 0.79;
sprites.yScale = 0.79;
[self addChild:sprites];
}
- (void) OneItemONLY {
     SKAction *appear = [SKAction scaleTo:0.79 duration:0.05];
     SKAction *waiter = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.5];
     SKAction *scaleDown = [SKAction scaleTo:0.0 duration:2.0];
     SKAction *remover = [SKAction removeFromParent];
     [sprites runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[appear, waiter, scaleDown, remover]]];
     [sprites runAction:appear];
 }
```

Comment: where do you add the image sprites as children? Note that scale actions will not affect the size of the physics bodies.

Comment: sorry bro I am not sure if I am following what your asking because the array is only using one skspritenode called sprites and now I know I got seven different sprites to play with but how would i pull them out of the array after they have been randomly presented to the scene and apply physics to them?

Comment: you never add image1-7 to an array, only b1-7 which you get from an array at random - so what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: you just said it I don't know how to add the image to the array because I don't want to add @"b1-7" but the image is a SKSpriteNode variable and for some reason the array wouldn't accept it as a param.

Comment: myArray = @[image1, image2]; you can fill in the rest. Alternatively  [.. initWithObjects:image1, image2, nil]; works the same way

Comment: Wow, so it is that simple?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51962/discussion-between-ray-and-learncocos2d)

Comment: How is physics not being applied here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not first set all the properties like this for each image?

```
-(NSMustableArray*)createMutableArrayOfImagesWithAmount:(int)amount andImageNamed:(NSString*)string{

    amount -= 1;

    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    SKSpriteNode *node;

    for (int i = 0, i <= amount, i++){

        node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", string, i]];

        node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:node.frame.size.width/2];
        node.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        node.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsimage1Category;
        node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsbulletCategory;
        [node attachDebugRectWithSize:node.size];

        [mutableArray addObject:node];
    }

    return mutableArray;

}
```

seems more suitable then re-typing the same thing seven times